# how to get scheduled notification using firebase cloud function

Tags: javascript, flutter, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have integrated firebase cloud messaging and trying to remind notification the users, when the appointments time before 5 min and my flutter app fetch data from api by own server,

For scheduled notification purpose, i have using firebase firestore database to save notification details and by reading the firebase firestore database for every 1 minute through firebase cloud function check comparison with current time and notification time call the fcm api and get the notification time

```
const admin = require("firebase-admin");

admin.initializeApp();
const database = admin.firestore();

exports.sendNotification = functions.pubsub.schedule("* * * * *").onRun(async (context) => {



var day = new Date();
        const options = { day: 'numeric', month: 'long', year: "numeric", hour: '2-digit', minute: '2-digit', timeZone: "Asia/Kolkata" };
         const today = day.toLocaleDateString("en-IN", options);
        console.log("today", today);


    const query = await database.collection("notification").where("time", "==", today).get();

    for (const snapshot of query.docs) {
        const data = await snapshot.data();
        console.log("yes comming", data);
        console.log(data.time, '==', strDate);

        sendNotification(snapshot.id, data);
    }

    function sendNotification(id, androidNotification) {
        const message = {
            condition: androidNotification.userid.length == 1 ? androidNotification.userid[0] : androidNotification.userid.join("||"),

            notification: {
                title: androidNotification.title,
                body: androidNotification.body
            },

            data: {
                id: id,
                click_action: "FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK"
            }


        };

        admin.messaging().send(message).then(async (response) => {

            await database.collection("notification").doc(id).delete().then((response) => console.log("Successfully Message deleted", response));
            console.log("Successful Message Sent");
            console.log(response.statusCode);
            return null;
        }).catch((error) => {

            console.log("Error Sending Message", error);

            return null;
        });
    }

    console.log("End Of Function");
    return null;
});
```

but the problem is only get the notification certain timezone how to change utc time
and is this right way to get scheduled notification

Comment: Could you elaborate a little more on your problem? Does the notification get send every 5 minutes currently and you do only what to change the timezone?

Comment: ok thanks, when the notification is need, First it could saved to firestore database and then every 1  minute, above function will execute if saved notification time is equal to utc time   and remove timezone